# Given $2P$ find $P$ on elliptic curve

Tags: polynomials, elliptic-curves

> Given $2P$ find $P$ on elliptic curve

If $C:y^2=x^3-4$ over $\mathbb Q$ then using division polynomials find $P$ s.t. $2P=(5,11)$, With the formulas [Here](http://www.math.umn.edu/~musiker/schoof.pdf#page=5) my problem is reduced to finding one solution $(x,y)$ with,

$4xy^2-3x^4+48x-20y^2=0$ and $4y(x^6-8x^3-128)-352y^4=0$ and wolframalpha yields [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4xy%5E2-3x%5E4%2B48x-20y%5E2%3D0%20and%204y(x%5E6-8x%5E3-128)-352y%5E4%3D0) and since the values are approximated I cannot test which of them satisfy the desired equation, can you help ?

Answer (score 2):

I have not checked the accuracy of the formulas you are using for the multiplication-by-2 map, but here is the formula for the $x$-coordinate of $2P$ that appears in Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" (Ch III, Group Law Algorithm 2.3), when simplified for your curve:
$$x(2P) = \frac{x^4+32x}{4x^3-16}.$$
Since $x(2P)=5$ in our case, we need
$$x^4+32x=5(4x^3-16)$$
or, equivalently, we need $x^4-20x^3+32x+80=0$. This polynomial has a unique linear factor over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, and this factor gives you a unique rational root which corresponds to the $x$-coordinate of the point $P$ you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks but I think I have to apply the divisor polynomials

Comment: Yes. What I am saying is that you are using them wrong, or the ones you are using have errors. The formula for x(2P) that you should be getting using division polynomials is the one I give here.